# React native firebase google login access Token returns Undefined

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, access-token, google-signin, refresh-token

My app has a Firebase based Google login. I am trying to get access Token but getting undefined.I am getting  the idToken but I need AccessToken and refresh Tokens.I need help

Here is my code :

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
    scopes: ['profile', 'email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'], //adding calender scope
      webClientId: '863338747777-9bshdpj951ga8nik9tbtua52ji0h06k4.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      offlineAccess: true,
      forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
    });
```

const onGoogleButtonPress = async()=> {

```
   try
   {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    const {accessToken, idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    const credential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      idToken,
      accessToken,
    );
    await auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
    
          console.log('IDToken: ',idToken,accessToken)
          console.log('AccessToken: ',accessToken)
   }
    catch(error)
    {
      console.log(error)
    }
    finally{
      setLoggedIn(true)
    }    
  }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my own problem. I am using a older library of React native google sign in. The new one is react native login google. The new package is returning the accessToken as well. So to get the refresh token we need to use a api
[This is the Link for that](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#exchange-authorization-code) .

We need several headers
[Take a look at them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWWum.jpg)

You will get the serverAuthCode from the googleSignin function while signing in .

```
const UserInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
```

Console log the UserInfo to get the serverAuthCode ,AccessToken and Refresh Token

[This is the Package I am using for googlesignIn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-login-google)

Answer (score 0):

Prabhakar I hope this link helpful for him.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/google-login-with-react-native-and-firebase/

Thank You

Comment: Thanks but this did'nt help